# How to mount central (two-legged) kickstand on normal bike frame

Tags: compatibility, hybrid-bike, accessories, touring-bikes, kickstand

I bought [this](https://www.ergotec.de/en/products/stander/sub/mittelmontage/produkt/zweibeinstander-double-flex-2.html) kickstand, but it has grooves in the top that the instructions said should slot into the "stand plate" on the frame.

[image]

My frame looks like [this](https://cdn.bike-discount.de/media/org/orgb_C/orgid_26/thumbs/471396_3993526.jpg): doesn't seem to have a plate of any kind, and the chainstays don’t fit into the grooves on the kickstand.

[image]

So is this kickstand a weird one that needs some kind of plate, or are all centre kickstands like this?   If so, how do I fit one to my frame - can I buy a separate base plate?  [This](https://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/hebie-bike-stand-plate-38717) was the only thing I could find like that..

[image]

Comment: There are a half-dozen different schemes for mounting kickstands (even limiting the discussion to bikes which are designed to accept kickstands).  You may simply have the wrong kickstand.   At the very least you're apt to need a longer bolt.

Comment: Even if you have got a plate bridging the chainstays, instead of the tube on your frame, it doesn't necessarily have anything to engage the grooves. Some double kickstands have a top plate, that would help you, but you have to be really careful not to do the bolt up too tight

Comment: Probably you already did get it, but the separate base plate has to be used together with [this](https://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/hebie-counter-plate-38719). Also use   Loctite, better a stronger version. Because those things tend to get loose. And using a piece of old tube between the frame and the plates might help to spread the pressure and protect the paint.

Comment: How did you get on with this kickstand ?  Did you get it mounted ?

Comment: Most regular bikes in central Europe came with a base plate for kick-stands braced or welded to the frame. Bikes intended for sports lacked it. It changed only recently when rear kick stands caused the base plate to become rare on vibes that are not meant for shopping or such.

Answer (score 4):

The groves are for any cables that are routed under the stays.
Your kickstand should have come with a counter plate - B in the picture below

Your kickstand is slightly different but the mounting instructions will be the same as the kickstand below

ergotec Double-leg kickstand Double Flex 3 [manual](https://www.ergotec.de/files/Produkte/W1187000_ergotec_Zweibeinstaender_DoubleFlex%203.pdf)

> **Bicycles without a stand plate**
>
> - Check if the distance between the housing of the bottom bracket bearings
>   on the frame and the tyre of the rear wheel is sufficient for the assembly
>   operation.
> - Now you attach supporting surface **C** from below to the chain stay on the
>   frame. If there are cables here you press these into the notches **D** provided
>   for this purpose.
> - Adjust the double-leg kickstand in such a way that when folded into place
>   there is space of at least 15 mm between the kickstand and the tyre of the
>   rear wheel.
> - Now you place counter plate **B** on the chain stay from above and fasten it with clamping screw **A**.
> - Tighten clamping screw **A** to a tightening value of 21- 23 Nm.
> - Finally you check that the chain can move freely. For this purpose you should
>   engage all the gears once.

[image]